# Laravel 4 - Return user id on save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im wondering if someone can help me out.

I need to create a record in my database when a user signs up which needs the users newly created ID.

I have my standard code to insert a user as follows.

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->save();
```

So i need the ID of the saved user.

Is that possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just call the ID afterwards as it is populated by Eloquent:

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->save();
echo $user->id;
```

Comment: `echo ($user->id)` ? `echo $user->id;` :-)